# mac os + apache 2.4.33 + python 3.7.2 + django 2.1.5 + mod_wsgi 4.6.5 (Site can't be reached)

Tags: python, django, macos, apache, mod-wsgi

I am facing issue in running the server(Site can't be reached) after python upgrade from 2.x to 3.7.2 Our server config:

- Mac OS 10.13.6 (High Sierra)
- Apache 2.4.33 custom installation
- Python 3.7.2 (Brew install python3)
- Django 2.1.5 (Installed via pip inside python 3 env)
- mod_wsgi 4.6.5 (Installed via pip inside python 3 env)

I have added the following two lines(mod_wsgi-express module-config) in httpd.conf file removing the python 2.7 references:

```
 LoadModule wsgi_module "/../MASP_ENV3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi-py37.cpython-37m-darwin.so"  
WSGIPythonHome "/../MASP_ENV3"
```

Also in httpd-vhosts.conf:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess mysite.com processes=2 threads=15 display-name=%{GROUP} python-home=/Library/WebServer/Documents/MASP_ENV3 python-path=/Library/WebServer/Documents/mysite 
WSGIProcessGroup mysite.com
WSGIScriptAlias / /Library/WebServer/Documents/mysite/wsgi.py
```

After restarting the server, when we hit the URL in the browser the page continues to load for a while(2-5 mins) and later displays "Site can't be reached"

It would be great if one can guide me with valuable suggestions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the virtual env not created in the python3 system installation directory. I fixed the issue by following this doc:
* https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html#location-of-the-virtual-environment

Also, my detailed conversation with mod_wsgi author is here:
https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/issues/396

Answer (score 0):

what is being reported in the apache error log?

Can you add the param request-timeout to WSGIDaemonProcess and set it to something low, say 30 seconds? after such a change do you get "Site not reached" in about 30 seconds or does it still take 2-5 mins?

Is the wsgi configuered to write logs anywhere? Can you see the request reaching the python app?

Sorry for writing the questions as an answer but I still dont have the needed level to add comments.

Comment: Nothing is being logged in Apache's error_log file. Currently, the log level is set to warn. Will change it to debug and cross verify. Anyways thanks for the suggestion.